# SwiftUI - JSON to Model Data stored returns nil (despite jsonstring data displaying)

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, decode

The JSON i'm trying to import into a Model isn't working correctly and returning ***nil***, i've read other similar issues around this but none seem to apply to my current configuration.

I'm imagining it's to do with how it's trying to store it, but i can't seem to figure out why. I've broken everything down into it's main components. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
        
    @State private var isRotating = 0.0
    @State private var updatesVM = UpdatesViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "circle.hexagonpath")
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(isRotating))
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)
                            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                        isRotating = 360.0
                    }
                }
                .foregroundColor(.teal)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                .font(.system(size: 70))
                
            Text("Finding Data")
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            await updatesVM.fetchUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

**UpdateModel**

```
import Foundation

struct UpdateList:Codable {
    let acf: Acf
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case acf
    }
}

struct Acf:Codable {
    let appMessage: String?
    let disableApp: Bool?
    let update: [Update]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case update
        case appMessage = "app_message"
        case disableApp = "disable_app"
    }
}

struct Update: Codable {
    let updateNote, updateDatetime: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case updateNote = "update_note"
        case updateDatetime = "update_datetime"
    }
}
```

**UpdateViewModel**

```
import Foundation

final class UpdatesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    func fetchUpdates() async {
        
        if let url = URL(string: "urlhiddenforprivacy-listedjsondownbelow") {
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    
                    // Converts Data to JSON String to confirm it pulls in data from JSON URL
                    if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print(jsonString) 
                    }
                    
                    // Decodes Data to Acf Model
                    if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Acf.self, from: data) {
                        print(decodedResponse)
                    }else{
                        print("Failed response")
                    }
                    
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**JSON (As presented in URL)**

```
{
  "acf": {
    "app_message": "We have temporarily disabled our app for server maintenance. This shouldn't take long, please check back later.",
    "disable_app": false,
    "update": [
      {
        "update_note": "Removed Product 9",
        "update_datetime": "2023-02-02 05:00:00"
      },
      {
        "update_note": "Added Product 77 & 120",
        "update_datetime": "2023-03-10 13:54:13"
      },
      {
        "update_note": "Happy New Year to our users!",
        "update_datetime": "2023-06-27 14:11:08"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring every error and response that would tell you anything. Print the error and response from the session and use do try catch instead of try?

Comment: @loremipsum For clarity i've done a few variations for this,  with do and catchs in multiple, but i don't get a helpful error, so i've been keeping it basic to see if i can understand from a different approach. The issue seems to be with decoding, but i can't seem to isolate the issue.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read this info: [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)
There are a number of issues with your code. You should be using `@StateObject var updatesVM = UpdatesViewModel()` in your `ContentView`, 
with some `@Published var theList: UpdateList?` and something like this, in `func fetchUpdates()`: 
`do { let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(UpdateList.self, from: data) 
                 theList = decodedResponse
                 ...} catch {print(error)}` in your `UpdatesViewModel`

Comment: Use `print(error)` in the `catch` it will tell you exactly what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with not accounting for the parent wrapper inside the JSON, from other stuff i've read it suggested i could do this, which wasn't the case.

All sorted, thank you, and sorry if i wasted anyones time, i'm new to this.